# Schengen visa for spouse, for business trip followed by leisure trip

Tags: schengen, europe, spain

I have to attend a business meeting in Spain for 5 days and after that I plan to have a trip in Europe with my wife, she will arrive after I complete my business meeting. Shall I apply for visa the separately - business and tourism visa for me, and tourism visa for her? Are there any implications doing this?

Comment: How did this go for eight months without being answered?

Comment: :) it was difficult with uncertainty in my mind. but as you mentioned in the answer, I applied for business visa for me and tourist visa for my wife, and mentioned about it in my cover letter. both of us were granted the respective visas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, the categorization of Schengen visas is not particularly strict, although you do have to select a "main purpose of the journey" on the application form.  The form is given in Annex I of the [Schengen Visa Code](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX:02009R0810-20160412).

In your case, this will be "business," and in your wife's case it will be "tourism."

> Shall I apply for visa the separately...?

You have to submit two application forms in any case, even if the purpose of the journey is the same, because the application form does not support multiple applicants.  You might want to submit your application first, in case your visa is not approved or is limited to just period of your anticipated business travel.  This would save your wife from having to apply for a visa for a trip on which you cannot accompany her.  But if you don't mind that possibility, you can certainly apply at the same time.  If traveling to the application center is burdensome, it might be better to do that and try to get appointments at the same time.